# How can I modify my function to hide the body of the messages as default and to show the body when clicked?

Tags: javascript

Here is my html with the JS within. The function "toggleMessage()" is the function I am using to hide and show messages when clicked. The problems I am running into include:

1. Messages showing by default, when they should hide by default (until clicked).
2. When clicked, all messages show at once - I want only the messages clicked on to show.
3. The new messages that populate the page every 3 seconds are not affected by the click event - I want them to be effected.

```js
function newMessage() {
  // Loop goes through emails and creats divs for subject, date, sender, and body
  var i = 0;
  while (i < window.geemails.length) {

    //email container
    var div = document.createElement("div");

    //date
    var dateField = document.createElement("h1");
    dateField.className = "date";
    dateField.innerHTML = window.geemails[i].date;
    div.appendChild(dateField);

    //subject
    var subjectField = document.createElement("h1");
    subjectField.className = "subject";
    subjectField.innerHTML = window.geemails[i].subject;
    div.appendChild(subjectField);

    //sender
    var senderField = document.createElement("h1");
    senderField.className = "sender";
    senderField.innerHTML = window.geemails[i].sender;
    div.appendChild(senderField);

    //body
    var bodyField = document.createElement("p");
    bodyField.className = "body";
    bodyField.innerHTML = window.geemails[i].body;
    div.appendChild(bodyField);

    //Separate message content into containers
    document.getElementById("main").appendChild(div);

    //inbox counter
    document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = "You have " + document.getElementsByClassName("date").length + " messages";

    window.geemails.shift();
  }

}


newMessage();



//interval for loading new messages
function addNewMessage() {
  setInterval(function() {
    window.geemails.push(getNewMessage());
    newMessage();
  }, 3000);
}

addNewMessage();

//hiding and showing body message upon click
var messageBox = document.getElementsByClassName("subject");

for (var i = 0; i < messageBox.length; i++) {
  messageBox[i].addEventListener("click", toggleMessage);
}

function toggleMessage() {
  var showMessage = document.getElementsByClassName('body');
  for (var i = 0; i < showMessage.length; i++) {
    if (showMessage[i].style.display === 'none') {
      showMessage[i].style.display = "block";
    } else {
      showMessage[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You toggleMessage is looping. Make it not loop and pass in what you want to toggle - You would be better off with jQuery and event delegation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a class for your messages and possiblt for their bodies.
Suppose you have a message div with a message body like this

```
 <div class="message">
     <div class="message-header">
     </div>
     <div class="message-body" style="display:none;">
     </div>
 </div>
```

if you want the body to be hidden by default use css `display:none`

then in your javascript do

```
$('.message').click(function(){
      $(this).children('.message-body').show();
});
```

Comment: The HTML is likely just <div id="main"></div><span id="counter"</span> and is missing event delegation

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for dealing with my noob question :) It works now, now the only way to make it even better would be to only show the body of the message for the div I click. Right now if I click on one div it opens all the other ones.

Comment: use the children method passing as selector the class  you want to pick among the children of the clicked element (see udpate in answeR)

Comment: Cool, I did that and while it worked to show only the divs I click on, the function is no longer working for new messages that populate the page every 3 seconds (from the setInterval())

Comment: put the javascript in the callback that is invoked after a new message is added